# Can I use C++ to write the source package for a .deb package?

Tags: packaging, deb

What programming language should I use to write a source package for a .deb package?

I want to package a C++ program.

Comment: You mean you want to package a C++ program, or that you want to write the packaging rules in C++?

Comment: Oh. Then you can use whatever language you want.

Comment: @user464180, you can package anything even create an empty a dummy one. You can look here for available packages a examples http://packages.ubuntu.com/ . You can list contained files.

Comment: C++ is a programming language of the compiled type which means that this language results on a binary which can be run it a compatible operative system.

Packaging applications is the way this binary also called software packages is then delivered to the user.

This packages have the task of the delivering the software files where it can be found by the application launcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Source code that requires compilation will be compiled when building the binary package; see [IntroDebianPackaging at wiki.debian.org](https://wiki.debian.org/IntroDebianPackaging) for instructions on how to create a source package containing source code that requires compilation.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways, but if your c++ program is built with cmake you can use the [cpack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html) module to generate a .deb file from the build.

[Here](https://github.com/MatrixManAtYrService/hello-cpp-linwin/blob/0dbfe2bb7acc39da3a7c3bc3ecb54eb1b0ddc5e7/CMakeLists.txt#L292) is an example.